# Is it possible to hide applications from the application tab in Local Scout?

Tags: local-scout, 7.x

In Local Scout, if you select a company, it will show their details, including an applications tab, which can show some useful connections (things like links to driving directions apps and things like that) - however, there are a few completely irrelevant applications in the list of those available to install, for example, "[Flashlight-X Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/857f5e58-6704-4f82-bbcf-2c4bf796e70b)" - is there any way to hide this application from the list?

Comment: The same thing happens in the Picture and Music & Video hubs.  I think it is down to the developer to accurately describe the abilities of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, those applications have now disappeared from the applications tab, so perhaps someone at Microsoft noticed -- I also see [from a blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/30/four-ways-we-re-improving-marketplace.aspx) that they're encouraging people to report applications that appear to have invalid keywords to reportapp@microsoft.com

Answer (score 2):

I think some apps show in Scout because the way depeloper opted in in [App Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202958%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Some apps can show in Music+Video Hub, Picture Hub, Scout and so on. Maybe this developer choose to show in Scout.